# Linq to SQL Repository ~theory~ - Generic but now uses Linq to Objects?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

The project I am currently working on used Linq to SQL as an ORM data access technology. Its an MVC3 Web app. The problem I faced was primarily due to the inability to mock (for testing) the DataContext which gets autogenerated by the DBML designer.

So to solve this issue (after much reading) I refactored the repository system which was in place - single repository with seperate and duplicated access methods for each table which ended up with something like 300 methods only 10 of which were unique - into a single repository with generic methods taking the  table and returning more generic types to the upper reaches of the application. The DataContext is now wrapped, and easily mocked.

[Edit: To achieve this i have used the link provided by Jacob below, coincidently!]

My question revolves more around the design I've used to get thus far and the differences I'm noticing in the structure of the app.

1) Having refactored the code which used classic Linq to SQL queries:

```
    public Billing GetBilling(int id)
    {
        var result = (
        from bil in _bicDc.Billings
        where bil.BillingId == id
        select bil).SingleOrDefault();
        return (result);
    }
```

it now looks like:

```
    public T GetRecordWhere<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        T result;
        try
        {
            result = _dataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and is used by the controller with a query along the lines of:

```
_repository.GetRecordWhere<Billing>(x => x.BillingId == 1);
```

which is fine, and precisely what I wanted to achieve.

...however.... I'm also having to do the following to get precisely the result set i require in the controller class (the highest point of the app in essence)...

```
viewModel.RecentRequests = _model.GetAllRecordsWhere<Billing>(x => x.BillingId == 1)
                .Where(x => x.BillingId == Convert.ToInt32(BillingType.Submitted))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).
                Take(5).ToList();
```

This - as far as my understanding is correct - is now using Linq to Objects rather than the Linq to SQL queries I was previously? Is this okay practise? It feels wrong to me but I dont know why. Probably because the logic of the queries is in the very highest tier of the app, rather than the lowest, but... I defer to you good people for advice. One of the issues I considered was bringing the entire table into memory but I understand that using the Iqeryable return type the where clause is taken to the database and evaluated there. Thus returning only the resultset i require... i may be wrong.

And if you've made it this far, well done. Thank you, and if you have any advice it is very much appreciated!!

**Update: Inclusion of GetAllRecordsWhere method as requested**

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetAllRecordsWhere<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        return _dataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

which uses:

```
    public IQueryable<TName> GetTable<TName>() where TName : class
    {
        return _db.GetTable<TName>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: What does the GetAllRecordWhere return? It should be an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: It is indeed an IQueryable<T>, as i mentioned at the end of the post - I beleive i read somewhere that subsquent .Where(predicate) etc. calls using an IQueryable get evaluated when called rather than pulling the lot into memory? Whether this is true or not...

Comment: Just nitpicking: the try-catch in GetRecordWhere is redundant - has it been simplified for the example? likewise, if `GetAllRecordsWhere` does what it says, ` then the line 
                .Where(x => x.BillingId == Convert.ToInt32(BillingType.Submitted))` is equivalent to `.Where(x => 1 == Convert.ToInt32(BillingType.Submitted))` - is that right?

Comment: @saus Correct, on both counts.

Comment: You probably need to post the signature of your GetAllRecordsWhere<T>. Does it take Expression<Func<T, bool>> or just Func<T, bool> if the later, then LINQ to Objects will be used because the version of Where that takes a Func<T, bool> extends IEnumerable, not IQueryable.

Comment: As another comment, you can simplify your GetMethodWhere to just 'result = _dataContext.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);' You don't need the Where clause.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jim - I think partially why this question remains unanswered is that I misunderstood what exactly the differerence was between Linq to Objects and Linq to SQL. As I am inded returning and using IQueryable rather than IEnumerable i will be forming expression trees with Linq to SQL and going down that route. I may have been getting tied up with the difference in syntax rather than the difference in the underlying code.

Comment: Also i read somewhere that Linq to SQL prefers having a precidate in the where clause rather than placing the predicate into the .SingleOrDefault. But theres a lot of not great advice out there....

Answer (score 1):

If `_model.GetAllRecordsWhere` returns an IQueryable then your subsequent querying is still just building up an expression tree (which is what i think you mean by using LinqToSql), it only gets turned into SQL an executed when you enumerate the collection by iterating over it or calling ToList() or ToArray().

As an aside don't do this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

All you are doing is swallowing the stack trace.  If you want to rethrow an exception just call `throw`, never `throw ex`. If you don't do anything in your catch other than rethrow then don't catch.  The nowmal pattern for this would be catch, do some logging, rethrow.

Comment: Its now being handled by a dedicated exception manager, being dealt with and being written to a file and DB so thanks but its just example code! Good point on the expression trees though. Thats more where I'm going with this. I'm trying to understand if my implementation of the generic repository is correct. (It works, but is it correct...?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock database context see this:

http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/06/mocking-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx

Comment: That is indeed what i have implemented, but not the subject of my question. Apologies if that was not clear. A good link none-the-less!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article that explains how to mock out your DataContext:

[Faking your LINQ provider part 1](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84)